# Wrapper layer to change kernel weights

Tags: tensorflow, keras, wrapper

I'm trying to write a custom wrapper layer such as the following one (simplified), where I want to modify the kernel weights of the wrapped layer:

```
import tensorflow as tf


class MyWrapper(tf.keras.layers.Wrapper):
    def __init__(self, layer: tf.keras.layers, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(layer, **kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        self.layer.kernel = self.layer.kernel + 1
        outputs = self.layer(inputs)
        return outputs


def main():
    # setup model
    input_shape = (8, 8, 1)
    xin = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    xout = MyWrapper(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(4, (3, 3), padding="same"))(xin)
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=xin, outputs=xout)
    model.compile()

    # run with output
    x_shape = (1, *input_shape)
    x = tf.random.uniform(x_shape, dtype=tf.float32)
    xout = model(x)
    print(xout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, the code breaks in the first line of the call function with the following output:

```
TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a
tf.init_scope in your function building code.
For example, the following function will fail:
  @tf.function
  def has_init_scope():
    my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
    with tf.init_scope():
      added = my_constant * 2
The graph tensor has name: my_wrapper/add:0
```

I've already checked https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/layers/WeightNormalization but am not sure whether it helps. While they also seem to redefine the kernel, they redefine it based on separate variables and not the kernel itself (in my understanding). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A kernel of a layer is  a `tf.Variable`. To change its value, use the `assign` method.

```
def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
    self.layer.kernel.assign(self.layer.kernel + 1)
    outputs = self.layer(inputs)
    return outputs
```

Its a common mistake to overwrite a `tf.Variable` with a Tensor. You can read more about `Variables`s in the guide: [Introduction to Variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variable).

A `Variable` even has some convenience methods like `assign_add`, that can shorten the code above to  `self.layer.kernel.assign_add(tf.ones_like(self.layer.kernel))`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer @Lescurel ! Just double checking: I believe .assign() can easily break the backward pass. But in this case, we should get the gradients w.r.t. the new kernel weights, or?  (gradient accumulation might be problematic, but this is not really relevant)

Comment: `we should get the gradients w.r.t. the new kernel weights, ` As far as I know, yes.

Comment: //P.s.: Also tested it on a mnist example, training works as expected